# gRPC streaming and thread safety

Tags: multithreading, grpc, grpc-java

Say I'm using gRPC server-side streaming. If I send multiple client requests in a for loop, in this case on the server side, multiple threads will run the same service instance, and they will share the same `StreamObserver` object. If in one thread, the `.onCompleted` is called, will it prevent other threads from calling `.onNext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamObserver` is not thread-safe, so should never be called from multiple threads simultaneously. The service instance is called multiple times, one for each server-streaming RPC. (For server-streaming RPCs, that is the same as once per client request.) But each time it is called it receives a different `StreamObserver` instance. You can call the different instances on different threads.

Since each RPC has its own `StreamObserver` instance, calling `onCompleted()` on one RPC has no impact to being able to call `onNext()` for a different RPC. The important part is to not call `onNext()` after `onCompleted()` for a single RPC/`StreamObserver` instance.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Since each service instance has its own copy of `StreamObserver` instance, I assume there's no need to do lock/synchronize on it?

Comment: Correct, there is no need to use a lock/whatever when calling the StreamObserver unless your service itself is scheduling work on other threads and causing multithreading.